# grant program more access

Tags: c#

Is there any way to grant  My Software full access on it's folder in `Program Files`,When I run windows Vista or Windows 7 and UAC is enabled?

My application can not write or delete it's files in Program File!

regards

Comment: NO!  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ Danial : My application can not write or delete it's files in Pogrom File!

Comment: Look at the Application manifest, one is normally create with a VS C# project. The options you have are listed there. Either way, you still gonna get a prompt to elevate.

Comment: @Ata: Your app should not modify files there. Only a setup program should. Data should be stored in the Application Data folder under an appropiate user.

Comment: Is there any folder that do not require permission and can be used for users , so if a user switch , there be not different .

Comment: @Ata: I think you can use the App Data folder in the 'Public' user/folder. Never tried it though.

Comment: @leppie: The correct place to put it is in the %CommonApplicationData% folder. on Windows 7 it is C:\ProgramData by default (but you should use the environment variable because that folder can be different)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing in the programs file folder is bad programming practice, that is the reason Microsoft made it so hard to do. Once the program has been set up it should never touch the program files directory unless it is being patched. If you need to save data it should be written to the folder

```
//Use this if you want different folder per user
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),"Your Application Name");

//Use this if you want the same folder per user
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData),"Your Application Name");
```

Comment: Sweet! Just what I was thinking :)