# Windows 7 doesn't allow me edit files in Common Application Data folder

Tags: c#, windows, uac

I want to store some files and edit them for my software in common Application Data under Windows 7.

I do not know why Windows 7 doesn't allow my software to change files 
unless I run them as administrator.

Where can I store my files, so it won't require admin permission?

Comment: @Henk : CommonApplicationData

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should store your application data in a subfolder under `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);` .  Note that this folder is user-specific.

Non-Admin users do not have permission to write to the `CommonApplicationData` folder, because that folder does not belong to specific users.

Note that you can also store your settings by using the Settings Class.  To do so, add New Item to your project, pick "Settings File".  This is appropriate for basic settings like strings and numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use elevation in order to modify those files, due to User Access Control. Take a look at this MSDN article for more details: [MSDN article about UAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511445.aspx)

If you are not sure how to do this in C#, here is an article: [Article about requesting elevation in C#](http://www.aneef.net/2009/06/29/request-uac-elevation-for-net-application-managed-code/)

Comment: +0: Requesting elevation just to save application settings is a bad idea.

Comment: elevation is not needed for writing Common App Data...
But Application should run inside Administrator Account....

Answer (score 3):

<s>Some folders are restricted starting in windows 7, these folders should not be touched unless you are installing, uninstalling, or patching. Please see [my answer that you accepted from earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942653/grant-program-more-access/3942748#3942748) it is the exact same case.</s>

If you have multiple aplications that need to edit the same files they should be stored in

```
Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

`System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles` (the folder I think you are trying to write to) is read only unless you are elevated.

read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2008/02/05/where-should-i-write-program-data-instead-of-program-files.aspx) from the MSDN it explains where you should be saving data and how do use the various folders correctly. My solution is the first one on his list, to summarize:

**You need to create a folder while you are installing the program in the CommonApplicationData folder then set permissions on that new folder so it will have write access from the users group.**

Comment: I have used this , and stored my files in this folder , but windows do not allow change !

Comment: Hmmm, I just checked my permissions on C:\ProgramData and it is read only... Hmmm

Comment: No , I have used CommonApplicationData , where can I store my files , so I will not require Admin Permission .

Comment: If your goal is to have settings shared between all users on a machine, this is a good solution.  If not, try one of my suggestions.  Turning off UAC is not a good way to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a security option turned on by default in windows 7 namely UAC (user Account Control). You should change your design (write somewhere else) or turn off UAC from control panel\User Accounts.

Comment: "You should change your design (write somewhere else)".. But, where?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this same problem, but using the Inno Setup Installer, I have a parameter named "Permissions" where I set the value "users-full" to create a file in my application folder into the common application data with full control for all users of that file.