# Installer options available in application?

Tags: c#, installation, setup-project

I have a basic installer with an option to install for all users or only for the current user. Based on this selection I copy several files in the common app data or the local app data.

My question is, how do I let my application know where have these files been installed. And I don't mean providing a hard coded path but more like providing the ability to choose between `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` (Single User) and `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` (All Users).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to always place them in the same location?  What I would do if this "had" to be done is use a CustomAction to Move the files from one location to another.  Of course the simple solution and the one Microsoft would likely suggest is to always place the files in the CommonApplicationData folder.

Comment: @Ramhound - I agree - it would be easier if you could enforce a mandate ([setup projects support this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f981xa1.aspx)), but if you are not in control of the installer distribution means - it could prove difficult.

Comment: That Makes sense. But I am worried about any User Account Control restrictions. We don't want to implement anything on that side and just want to use a user folder to keep data, without having to worry with issues of windows security. Does the CommonApplicationData folder require elevated privileges for writing data in it?

Comment: @Paul - Non-admins cannot write to [`CommonApplicationData`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3945791/175679)

Answer (score 1):

You should send the [ALLUSERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [custom action data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to a installer class using the installer [Custom Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Here is a great [custom action installer example](http://devdump.wordpress.com/2009/01/17/setup-project-custom-actions/) that uses Regasm to register .NET assemblies.

Once you have your installer custom action and custom action data - you can store it somewhere where your application can retrieve it - either in the registry, application config, or to a fixed location on disk.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to figure out which folder your data is in from your application is to check the LocalApplicationData, and if something is there, use it, else check the CommonApplicationData folder.