# Access denied error when writing to Application.CommonAppDataPath

Tags: c#, winforms, filestream

I have this code to write to the Application.CommonAppDataPath:

```
            using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                 ..................
            }
```

That way, I receive an access denied exception. What is it going on?

Comment: Maybe the application do not have access to the file?

Comment: I have found this curiosity. The application creates the file correctly. The problem is when it tries to rewrite the file. I went to that folder and checked that the file was created as read only priviledge for users. How can I create a file using read write access for users?

Comment: give a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945600/windows-7-doesnt-allow-me-edit-files-in-common-application-data-folder

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to permissions of the user creating the file. At first, the file was created at installation time when running application as administrator. Then, the application is run as a normal user. Furthermore, I needed also to share the created files among all users in system.

To solve all the problems, I have added this helper function which is called after creation of files:

```
    public static bool GrantAccess(string fullPath, bool readOnly)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), readOnly ? FileSystemRights.Read : FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
        return true;
    }
```